# Problem with compiling DLL (CURL library) (Visual Studio)

Tags: c++

I have a problem with compiling DLL in C++. I am using CURL library for HTTP POST.

When I compile my code as Console App, I do not get compile errors. But that same code gets Unresolved external symbol errors.

Lines like:

```
curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);

curl = curl_easy_init();

curl_easy_setopt(...);
curl_mime_name(...);
```

What I am doing wrong with dll? What is missing?

Here is the the code:

```
// dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
#define CURL_STATICLIB
#include "pch.h"
#include "CURL/curl.h"

#pragma comment (lib, "CURL/libcurl_a.lib")

__declspec(dllexport) int httpPOST();

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule,
    DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
    LPVOID lpReserved
)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

int httpPOST() {
    CURL* curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);

    curl = curl_easy_init();

    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_DEFAULT_PROTOCOL, "https");
        struct curl_slist* headers = NULL;
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Cookie: cmslog=1");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
        curl_mime* mime;
        curl_mimepart* part;
        mime = curl_mime_init(curl);
        part = curl_mime_addpart(mime);
        curl_mime_name(part, "username");
        curl_mime_data(part, "user", CURL_ZERO_TERMINATED);
        part = curl_mime_addpart(mime);
        curl_mime_name(part, "requestcode");
        curl_mime_data(part, "123456", CURL_ZERO_TERMINATED);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Code inside **httpPOST()** compiles without problems in console app.

Errors are:

> Error  LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_global_init

> Error  LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_init

> Error  LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_setopt

> Error  LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_slist_append

> Error  LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_mime_init

...

> Error  LNK1120 8 unresolved externals

Comment: Can you share the error message?

Comment: My crystal ball tells me you're not linking the CURL library; you're consuming the headers to do your compile, but link-time is missing all the CURL things you  referenced because the library is either missing or never added. Are you *sure* `CURL/libcurl_a.lib` is correct ?

Comment: I have added errors. `CURL/libcurl_a.lib` is correct, I have checked it again. @Jean-MarcVolle @WhozCraig

Comment: Most probably you do not build the dll the same way you built the console app. Do you have strictly the same threading/debug options?

Comment: Wrong library flavor.  If linking the *static* curl library is actually intended then you need to define CURL_STATICLIB in the consuming project.  This is not well standardized btw, [alternative](https://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2018/03/13/using-curl-library-from-c-on-windows/).

Comment: @HansPassant, thank you. Your answer helped me to find solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was in `#define CURL_STATICLIB` order.

Corect order is:

```
#include "pch.h"
#define CURL_STATICLIB
#include "CURL/curl.h"
```

Thank you all for help.